# Is there a way to keep global submodule cache instead of <project>/.git/modules/<submodule>?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a multiple projects which are using some common submodules. Some of those submodules are really huge. Now each of these projects are keeping whole copy of the repo in their `.git/modules` directory.
I am wondering, if there is a way to keep a single global copy of these submodules.

I think cloning submodule as a separate repo and giving all pojects that local url will be one way.
But how can I do it without changing submodule repo urls in the main repo as it will be problem for other contributors if I change url?
Is there an official way or a workaround?